# I have the Netbean blues

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

Here is the cliff notes version
I had to reinstall Windows 7 I have the pro 
version.  This is was due to my fault.

All data for that drive was saved.
So I reinstalled Netbeans
I have to reinstall Java too
Maybe that is why it won’t load?
I will follow the godmode advice info
When trying to have Netbeans recognize my
projects it doesn’t. The directories are there

Worst case scenario I would have to redo
everything,if I think it’s worth it.

Comment: It's a valid question, but you'll get better responses on superuser.  voting to migrate, hence the "close".

Comment: @Thufir If it is _"a valid question"_ then _"you'll get better responses on superuser"_ is not a valid reason to vote to close. You are also in the very strange position of voting to close a question that you also chose to answer.

Comment: well, ya got me.  It's not off topic, but it's more on topic elsewhere.  My "answer" is just a stab in the dark.  Also, new user, trying to be friendly.

Comment: @Thufir Fair enough, though I think it is less likely that folks on superuser will be able to assist. FYI, as a related matter, there is currently a debate on meta about the validity of questions like this on SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378140/why-was-a-question-about-installing-netbeans-closed-for-seeking-recommendations

Comment: To be clear larry - you have Netbeans projects on your machine but you can't load them in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots of whatever's happening, please.

Without more data to go by, perhaps there's a versioning problem between your `JDK` and `NB`.  What is the output for `javac -version`?  I'm running `NB` 8.2 so my system is as so:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_191
thufir@dur:~$
```

If you're running `NB` 9, then you want `JDK` 9+.